# How To Dispose PagingController(infinite_scroll_pagination) In GetxController?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to release everything when leaving the current screen.

Getx advising me to use `onClose` method of `GetxController` for this.

```
@override
void onClose() {
  pagingController.dispose();
  super.onClose();
}
```

He kept his promise, so nice. But it didn't take long! Let's dive in;

The controller has a future method called `_fetchPage`, it basically fetches page data and works with `pagingController`

If I leave the screen before completing the `_fetchPage`, the future remains working. Once the data is fetched, `pagingController` is accessed but it has been already disposed.

And finally, it prints `Unhandled Exception: Exception: A PagingController was used after being disposed.`

```
  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      var skip = pageKey == 0 ? 0 : (10 * pageKey);
      var data = await fetchDataOfPage(skip, limit);
      final isLastPage = data.length < limit;

      if (isLastPage) {
        pagingController.appendLastPage(data);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        pagingController.appendPage(data, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }
```

Comment: There are few things you have to take care:

1. make sure you have all the variables in controller.
2. you dont have to actually dispose the controller if the controller is bind with the route. So make sure you have bindings binded with the route using 
   
GetPage(
      name: _Paths.POST_DETAIL,
      page: () => FeedItemDetail(),
      binding: SocialFeedBinding(),
    ).

so when the page is popped all the controller data will be deleted

Comment: The pagingController is defined in the controller and bound with Binding.  I can see the lifecycle logs of the Controller. But `infinite_scroll_pagination` docs emphasized using dispose method especially.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and was able to fix it by checking that the widget is still mounted after retrieving the data:

```
  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      var skip = pageKey == 0 ? 0 : (10 * pageKey);
      var data = await fetchDataOfPage(skip, limit);

      // bail out if widget is no longer mounted
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }

      final isLastPage = data.length < limit;

      if (isLastPage) {
        pagingController.appendLastPage(data);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        pagingController.appendPage(data, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.

> https://github.com/EdsonBueno/infinite_scroll_pagination/pull/7#issuecomment-712956309

```
class _FooListViewState extends State<_FooListView> {
  final PagingController<int, Foo> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);
  Object _activeCallbackIdentity;

  @override
  initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) => _fetchPage(pageKey));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    _activeCallbackIdentity = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    final pageSize = 10;

    final callbackIdentity = Object();
    _activeCallbackIdentity = callbackIdentity;
    try {
        final newItems = await RemoteAPI.getFoosByStatus(
          widget.status,
          limit: pageSize,
          offset: pageKey,
        );

        if (callbackIdentity == _activeCallbackIdentity) {
            final isLastPage = newItems.length < pageSize;
            if (isLastPage) {
              _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
            } else {
              final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
              _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (callbackIdentity == _activeCallbackIdentity) {
            _pagingController.error = error;
        }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () => Future.sync(() => _pagingController.refresh()),
      child: PagedListView<int, Foo>(
        pagingController: _pagingController,
        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Foo>(
          itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => _FooListItem(item),
          newPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (context) => Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```